# ValueError at /category/leather/all/ Field 'id' expected a number but got 'leather'

Tags: django

This is my views.py.

```
def category(request,type):
    prods=Product.objects.filter(category=type)
    context = {
        'categories':Category.objects.all(),
        'prods' : prods,
    }    
    return render(request,"category.html",context)
```

This is my models.py for reference

```
class Category(models.Model):
    type=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

What is happening is that when I pass leather(or any other category) as type parameter in url it gives me the error.What I am wanting to do is that if I pass leather then the products should filter by leather category which I am not able to make happen. If I pass an id corresponding to the category then it works fine. I wanted to know a way so that the type can be read properly and then filter accordingly.

Comment: Can you please share your urls.py

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to filter your `Product` objects by the `category` field. However, since this field is a foreign key referencing to a `Category` object, you cannot simply filter by a string like this.

Instead, you could do this to filter directly by the category's 'type':

```
prods = Product.objects.filter(category__type=type)
```

This tells Django to filter on the field `type` of the category object that is referenced by foreign key in the `Product` model. When using double underscores (`__`) when filtering you are indicating that you want to reference a field in the related model. This works recursively as well. See the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/) for more info on filtering.